# Firebase observeSingleEventOfType keeps calling in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

Acorrding to the Firebase documentation, the block of the function `observeSingleEventOfType` is immediately canceled after the initial data is returned, but it doesn't in my case.
I have this code:

```
DataService.dataService.USERS_REF.childByAppendingPath(DataService.dataService.CURRENT_USER_ID).childByAppendingPath("groups").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FDataSnapshot] {

        DataService.dataService.GROUPS_REF.childByAppendingPath(snap.key).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot2 in
            if snapshot2.exists() {
                print(snapshot2)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

The problem that I have is that, when I add some data in `GROUPS_REF`(the nested function), this nested function doesn't get called since is `observeSingleEventOfType` and the block is cancelled, but doesn't happen same thing when I add some data in `USERS_REF`, that provoques to call again the main function and it's nested function. Both are `observeSingleEventOfType`so they both shouldn't get called. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is this a Firebase bug?